# Mayavi: plot a GRID in a 3d surface

Tags: 3d, grid, surface, mayavi

I'm trying to plot a grid in the flat surface of this graph. I mean lines for each value of the x and y axis. But I don't know how to do it in mayavi. I will appreciate it if somebody can help me.
This is my code:

```
from mayavi import mlab
x=np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
y=np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])

X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)

Z=np.full((6,5),0.)
Z[0,0]=1
Z[-1,-1]=1
     
s=mlab.mesh(X,Y,Z)
mlab.colorbar( orientation='vertical', nb_labels=5)  
mlab.show()
```

[And it is the plot][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ2wd.png